# Building a geodesic conjugate parameterization on catenoid

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations, surfaces, integrable-systems

I believe that a catenoid supports a parametrization $\sigma : U \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ that forms a conjugate system (i.e., $\sigma_{uv} \in\mathrm{span}(\sigma_u, \sigma_v)$) with the additional property that the coordinate curves are geodesics. I tried the following computational approach in building such a prameterization. I chose the following usual parameterization of a catenoid:

$$ \sigma = \left(\begin{array}{c} \cosh(u) \cos(v),\\
                                    \cosh(u) \sin(v),\\
                                    u\end{array}\right) $$

I assumed that there is a coordinate transformation $u = \phi(x,y)$ and $ v = \psi(x,y)$ such that they would give me the result I need.
Upon computing the following conditions that ensure the geodesic-conjugate properties

- conjugate property $\det(\sigma_x,\sigma_y,\sigma_{xy}) = 0$
- geodesic x-coordinates $\det(N,\sigma_x,\sigma_{xx}) = 0$
- geodesic y-coordinates $\det(N,\sigma_y,\sigma_{yy}) = 0$

where $N$ is the Gauss map, I arrived to the following system of PDEs:

- $\ln \left(\psi_{x}\right)-\ln \left(\phi_{x}\right) = 
  \ln \left(\psi_{y}\right)-\ln \left(\phi_{y}\right)
  $
- $\frac{{\partial}}{{\partial}y}\ln \left(\psi_{y}\right)-\frac{{\partial}}{{\partial}y}\ln \left(\phi_{y}\right)
   = 
  \frac{\left(\phi_{y}^{2}+\psi_{y}^{2}\right) \tanh \left(\phi \right)}{\phi_{y}}$
- $\frac{{\partial}}{{\partial}x}\ln \left(\psi_{x}\right)-\frac{{\partial}}{{\partial}x}\ln \left(\phi_{x}\right)=\frac{\left(\phi_{x}^{2}+\psi_{x}^{2}\right) \tanh\left(\phi \right)}{\phi_{x}}$

Can someone clarify how I can continue from here? Unfortunately I don't know much about PDEs but I still believe that there should be an answer to this.

Comment: I think that there must be something wrong with your equations.  The first equation implies that $\psi_x\phi_y-\psi_y\phi_x=0$, but this iimplies that $\phi$ and $\psi$ cannot be independent functions of $(x,y)$.  Surely you have a typo somewhere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I thought about your problem and realized that there is no coordinate parametrization of the catenoid with the properties that you want.

Here is my argument:  First, note that, in the given $uv$-parametrization, the first and second fundamental forms of the immersion are
$$
I= \cosh(u)^2 (\mathrm{d}u^2 + \mathrm{d}v^2)
\quad\text{and}\quad
I\!I = \mathrm{d}u^2- \mathrm{d}v^2.
$$
We want to find two (possibly local) foliations by geodesics,
say $\mathcal{F}_i$ for $i=1,2$, such that the tangent vectors to the leaves of one foliation are conjugate to the tangent vectors to the leaves of the other foliation.  What this means is that,
if $X$ is a vector field tangent to the leaves of $\mathcal{F}_1$ and $Y$ is a vecor field tangent to the leaves of $\mathcal{F}_2$, then $I\!I(X,Y)=0$.

Of course, we can assume, without loss of generality, that $X$ and $Y$ are unit vector fields, i.e., $I(X,X)=I(Y,Y)=1$.

Now, given any unit tangent vector field to the surface, say, $Z$, the condition that the flow lines of $Z$ be geodesics is that $Z^\flat$, the dual $1$-form, be closed.

Thus, we require that $X$ and $Y$ be unit vector fields so that $I(X,X)=I(Y,Y)=1$ and that $X^\flat$ and $Y^\flat$ be closed, and we also require that $I\!I(X,Y) = 0$, since this is the conjugate property.  If
$$
X^\flat = \cosh u\,(\cos\alpha\,\mathrm{d}u +\sin\alpha\,\mathrm{d}v),
$$
for some angle function $\alpha$, then
the equations $I(Y,Y)=1$ and $I\!I(X,Y) = 0$ force
$$
\pm Y^\flat =  \cosh u\,(\sin\alpha\,\mathrm{d}u +\cos\alpha\,\mathrm{d}v).
$$
Note that $\cos(2\alpha)\not=0$, otherwise, $X\pm Y = 0$, and the two foliations will not be transverse, so they can't be the level sets of the desired coordinate functions.

So we need that the following $1$-forms be closed:
$$
\xi = \cosh u\,(\cos\alpha\,\mathrm{d}u +\sin\alpha\,\mathrm{d}v) \quad\text{and}\quad
\eta = \cosh u\,(\sin\alpha\,\mathrm{d}u +\cos\alpha\,\mathrm{d}v).
$$
If we take the exterior derivatives of these 1-forms and set them equal to zero, we find that $\alpha$ must satisfy the equation
$$
\mathrm{d}\alpha = \frac{\tanh u}{\cos 2\alpha}\,
\bigl(\mathrm{d}v - \sin 2\alpha\, \mathrm{d}u\bigr).
$$
But now applying the exterior derivative to both sides of this relation, we see that
$$
0 = \frac{1-2\cosh^2u}{\cosh^2u\,\cos 2\alpha}\,\mathrm{d}u\wedge\mathrm{d}v.
$$
Since $1-2\cosh^2u$ is never zero, we have a contradiction, so $\alpha$ cannot exist.

**Remark:**  For comparison, it might be helpful to look at the case of the helicoid, parametrized by $(u\cos v, u\sin v, v)$.  Here we have
$$
I= \mathrm{d}u^2 + (u^2{+}1)\mathrm{d}v^2
\quad\text{and}\quad
I\!I = \frac{2 du\,dv}{\sqrt{u^2{+}1}}.
$$
now, reasoning as above, we seek an angle $\alpha$ such that the $1$-forms
$$
\xi = \cos\alpha\,\mathrm{d}u +\sin\alpha\,\sqrt{u^2{+}1}\,\mathrm{d}v
\quad\text{and}\quad
\eta = \cos\alpha\,\mathrm{d}u -\sin\alpha\,\sqrt{u^2{+}1}\,\mathrm{d}v
$$
are closed.  The equation $\mathrm{d}(\xi+\eta)=2\,\mathrm{d}(\cos\alpha\,\mathrm{d}u)=0$ implies that $\alpha$ must
be a function of $u$ and the equation $\mathrm{d}(\xi-\eta)=2\,\mathrm{d}(\sin\alpha\,\sqrt{u^2{+}1}\,\mathrm{d}v)=0$ then implies
that $\sin\alpha\,\sqrt{u^2{+}1} = c$ for some constant $c\not=0$.
Thus,
$$
\xi = \sqrt{\frac{u^2{+}1{-}c^2}{u^2{+}1}}\,\mathrm{d}u +c\,\mathrm{d}v
\quad\text{and}\quad
\eta = \sqrt{\frac{u^2{+}1{-}c^2}{u^2{+}1}}\,\mathrm{d}u -c\,\mathrm{d}v,
$$
defined on the range where $u^2{+}1{-}c^2>0$ (which is everywhere if $|c|<1$).  The dual vector fields are
$$
X_\pm = \sqrt{\frac{u^2{+}1{-}c^2}{u^2{+}1}}\,
\frac{\partial}{\partial u} \pm \frac{c}{u^2{+}1}\,\frac{\partial}{\partial v},
$$
so we choose $x$ and $y$ so that $\mathrm{d}x$ and $\mathrm{d}y$
each annihilate one of $X_\pm$, say
$$
\mathrm{d}x = \mathrm{d}v 
+\frac{c\,\mathrm{d}u}{\sqrt{(u^2{+}1{-}c^2)(u^2{+}1)}}
\quad\text{and}\quad
\mathrm{d}y = \mathrm{d}v 
-\frac{c\,\mathrm{d}u}{\sqrt{(u^2{+}1{-}c^2)(u^2{+}1)}},
$$
which gives a 1-parameter family of solutions to the problem.

Comment: How can we assume that the coordinate vector field $X$ and $Y$ are unit vector fields? This is not obvious for me or maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @ArvinRasoulzadeh:  They are not the coordinate vector fields, but they are multiples of the coordinate vector fields.  You can always take the coordinate vector fields (which are nonvanishing) and divide by their lengths in the induced metric.  The resulting unit vector fields $X$ and $Y$ aren't coordinate vector fields any more because $[X,Y]$ is (usually) nonzero, but that doesn't affect whether they are conjugate with respect to $I\!I$.

Comment: I got really interested in this sentence:
"the condition that the flow lines of  be geodesics is that ♭, the dual 1-form, be closed."
I know that this might be a trivial question but can you please tell me how we know this?

Comment: @ArvinRasoulzadeh:  Yes, it follows from this:  If $g ={ \omega_1}^2 + {\omega_2}^2$ where $\omega_1 = Z^\flat$, and $\kappa(p)$ is the geodesic curvature of the flow line of $Z$ through a point $p$ of the surface, then $\mathrm{d}\omega_1 = \kappa\,\omega_1\wedge\omega_2$ (a consequence of the structure equations).  Thus, $\omega_1$ is closed if and only if $\kappa$ vanishes identically, i.e., the flow lines of $Z$ are geodesics.